# css ios webkit object-fit failing to correctly honor object-position

Tags: html, css, mobile

EDIT: had originally said the wrong iOS version (it's basically the latest, 9.3.5)

EDIT: thanks to the kind soul who edited the question to include the snippet.
not sure why my chrome browser is not allowing editing of snippets in the question editor anymore.

First up:
I tried to make a stack snippet for this question, but unfortunately the snippets editor is not allowing me to edit any code in chrome on a chromebook. I'm not entirely sure why stack overflow don't just write a simple importer that converts a jsfiddle link into the stack snippet format. If the editor does not work, I am forced to resorting to much maligned cut and paste code and link question format.

Anyway the link for my fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/vwm2opf7/1/

A "full screen" link for that fiddle is

https://jsfiddle.net/vwm2opf7/1/embedded/result/

(because my issue is a mobile web issue it's best just loading that second link to observe the problem).

The code portions are here

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#div_page_header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #102339;
}
#div_image_banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
#img_banner_pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-position: top left;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="div_page_header">
    <div id="div_image_banner">
      <img alt="logo" src="http://www.graphicdesignbylisa.com/wp-content/uploads/generic-logo.jpg" id="img_banner_pic">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

What I'm expecting it to see the logo graphic auto scaled,and inset 10px from the top left hand corner, and scaled to fit vertically to 10px from the bottom of the blue box, with the aspect ratio retained. basically exactly like this:

[image]

now in chrome on the desktop, it behaves correctly
on android chrome, it behaves correctly also.
using any browser (eg safari, chrome, opera, even the lastpass browser) on an iphone 4S running iOS 9.3.5, you get the logo image centered in the blue panel.
I'm assuming it a webkit issue.

[image: iphone4S chrome]

I'm after a css-only solution to correctly position the logo, with scaling.

The reason for the 2 div approach, is i have found (in desktop at least) the only way to get the object-position to work correctly with an inset is to do this which then allows 100% to be used for width and height. even a calc (100%-20px) does not work properly. the reason for the inset is i'm using media queries to fine tune positioning for different sized screens. (not in this example, but i prefer to reduce example code to the bare minimum to show the problem, as in doing this it reduces complexity, and often I find the solution before finishing the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Safari 7.1-9.1 support `object-fit` but not `object-position` (see [`object-fit` on caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit))

No way around it other than using a polyfill like [object-fit-images](https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images) that will also fix `object-fit` in IE9+

Comment: i updated the jsfiddle to include that polyfill https://jsfiddle.net/vwm2opf7/18/ but it doesn't seem to work properly for object-position. am i implementing it correctly? embedded version here https://jsfiddle.net/vwm2opf7/18/embedded/result

Comment: Yes, make sure you read the polyfill's readme, you're missing the `font-family`: https://jsfiddle.net/8twumunh/